# how to do simple login verification in android?

Tags: android

i have created the login screen but i am unable to verify the data in the edit box..
i have tried for simple verification using following function that checks whether the username and password are same..

```
protected boolean isValid(String string1,String string2) {
```

if(string1.equals(string2))
   return true;
  else
  return false;

}

but it is not working properly...

Comment: can you post some more code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `EditText` widget of android in you layout:

put this in your xml layout:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/username"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Verify"
android:onClick="isValid"
/>
```

now in you activity enter validation code:

```
public void isValid(View view){//signature is mandated

String validUsername="username";
EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);

if(username.getText.toString().equals(validUsername)){
//Username is valid perform you logic here.
}

}
```